# Text Widget Not Working

Tags: widgets, widget-text

I have 2 widgets in the right sidebar. Both use HTML code to link a graphic to another page. The first one won't link for some reason and the second one does. If I swap the order, the same thing - the first one doesn't link and the second one does. Here is the site: http://eduardosmexicankitchen.com/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your posts are too wide and are overlapping the sidebar. Try changing your CSS to:

```
.entry-content {
width:55%;
}
```

**Revision:**

```
#secondary.widget-area{
display:block;
position:relative;
}
```

> This isn't a WordPress question, but since I've started trying to help
>   I thought I'd see it through.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your response. I put it to exactly that and the widget still was not linking to the proper link. I changed it back since it did not fix the issue.

Comment: See my revision to get it to work. It's a quick fix, you should set correct width for, article #post, .entry-content, and #primary.